# Collecting student grades, calculating the average, letter grade and display it using C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that needs to start by asking the user for student name. Program prompts 
the user for a student quiz score. when the user enters -99 the program will calculate the average and corresponding letter grade according to the following scale:

- 0-59=F
- 60-69=D
- 70-79=C
- 80-89=B
- 90-100=A

The program needs to display the student name, their average, and letter grade. The program needs to ask if they want to process another student, if the answer is 'Y' or 'y' process is repeated all over again, otherwise, program exit.

1) when I run the program (Enter the name of the student:) displays first, this displays correctly, I then press enter.

2) when I enter 99,88,77,69 the output is correct. when I enter these two -1, 101 the output is correct but then when i enter -99 it shows the wrong output.

3) when I enter my name then -99 my name shows, the nan and A shows thats incorrect. However would you like to process another student  shows correctly

4) when I select the lowercase y and n the program may exit without showing have a nice day.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int SENTINEL = -99;

    string student_name;
    int quiz_Score, counter = 0, accumulator =0;
    double average;
    char grade, user_input;

    cout << "Enter the name of the student:" << endl;
    getline(cin, student_name);

    cout << "Enter the score of the quiz between 1 and 100: " << endl;
    cin >> quiz_Score;

    while (quiz_Score != SENTINEL)
    {
        while (quiz_Score < 0 || quiz_Score > 100)
        {
            cout << "Value out of range" << endl;
            cout << "Enter a quiz score between 1 and 100: " << endl;
            cin >> quiz_Score;
        }
            counter ++;
           accumulator = accumulator + quiz_Score;

       cout << "Enter the score of the quiz between 1 and 100: " << endl;
        cin >> quiz_Score;

    }
    average = static_cast<double>(accumulator) / counter;

     if (average > 0 && average < 60)
        {
            grade = 'F';
        }
            else if (average >= 60 && average < 70)
        {
                grade = 'D';
        }
                else if (average >= 70 && average < 80)
        {
                    grade = 'C';
        }
                    else if (average >= 80 && average < 90)
        {
                            grade = 'B';
        }
                        else
        {
                                grade ='A';
        }
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << setw(20) << student_name << setw(20) << average << setw(20) << grade << endl;

         cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

         cout << "Would you like to process another student (Y/N): " << endl;
         cin >> user_input;
         cin.sync();

         if (user_input == 'N'){
            cout << "Have a good day" << endl; }
         if (user_input == 'Y')
         {
             cout << "Enter the name of the student:" << endl;
    getline(cin, student_name);

    cout << "Enter the score of the quiz between 1 and 100: " << endl;
    cin >> quiz_Score;

    while (quiz_Score != SENTINEL)
    {
        while (quiz_Score < 0 || quiz_Score > 100)
        {
            cout << "Value out of range" << endl;
            cout << "Enter a quiz score between 1 and 100: " << endl;
            cin >> quiz_Score;
        }
            counter ++;
           accumulator = accumulator + quiz_Score;

       cout << "Enter the score of the quiz between 1 and 100: " << endl;
        cin >> quiz_Score;

    }
    average = static_cast<double>(accumulator) / counter;

     if (average > 0 && average < 60)
        {
            grade = 'F';
        }
            else if (average >= 60 && average < 70)
        {
                grade = 'D';
        }
                else if (average >= 70 && average < 80)
        {
                    grade = 'C';
        }
                    else if (average >= 80 && average < 90)
        {
                            grade = 'B';
        }
                        else
        {
                                grade ='A';
        }
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << setw(20) << student_name << setw(20) << average << setw(20) << grade << endl;

         cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
         }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What's your question? You've posted a code, but you didn't tell us what's wrong with it.

Comment: Oops! It's not executing properly. I have images, do you need to see them?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? For some specific input, what is its expected and actual output? And perhaps all you really want is a simple loop to repeat the main parts of the code?

Comment: Or is the problem that the newline left in the buffer by the `Enter` key after asking if the user want to continue makes the code skip the fetching of the student name the second time?

Comment: not sure what your saying. I put cin.ignore(); above cin.sync(); and ran the program again. I manage to fix the lowercase 'y' and 'n' by adding the OR operators.

Answer (score 1):

If the first score you enter is -99 then your input loop will stop immediately. At this point `accumulator` and `counter` are still 0, so the statement

```
average = static_cast<double>(accumulator) / counter;
```

computes 0/0. That is not defined and hence the result is `NaN`.

For inputting data for a second student, rather than duplicating the code for the first student, you should use another loop.

Finally, when you ask whether to answer data for another student, you check the answer only against `N` and `Y`, but not against `y`. So if you enter `y` then none of the two branches is executed. The code just silently exits.